# Alert only pops up when Chrome DevTools are open

Tags: javascript, json, ajax, dom, flask

I am trying to make a chatroom application using flask, SQLAlchemy, AJAX, and JSON. One of the features I am trying to implement is when one user is in a chatroom that someone else has created, if that chatroom is deleted a message pops up and they are redirected back to the main page.

My issue is when I test this with one user in a regular chrome window, and the other user in a incognito window (so they don't share the same cookie jar) the alert doesn't show unless I have the chrome DevTools open on the side.

Here is my js code:

```
function requestResponse() {
    if (httpRequest.readyState == XMLHttpRequest.DONE) {
        if (httpRequest.status == 200) {
            var messages = JSON.parse(httpRequest.responseText);
            if (messages == "deleted") {
                alert("The owner has deleted the chatroom.");
                window.location.href = "/login";
            } else if (messages.length != 0) {
                var table = document.querySelector(".message-board");
                for (var i = 0; i < messages.length; i++) {
                    var row = document.createElement("tr");
                    var cell = document.createElement("td");
                    cell.innerHTML = messages[i].content;
                    row.appendChild(cell);
                    table.appendChild(row);
                    lastUpdate = messages[i].time;
                }
                updateScroll();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here is my python api route:

```
@app.route('/api/chatroom', methods = ['GET', 'POST'])
def handle_room():
    if ("chatroom" in session):
        if request.method == 'GET':
            lastUpdate = request.args.get("last")
            chatroom = Room.query.filter_by(name = session["chatroom"]).first()
            if chatroom:
                newMessages = [message.makeDict() for message in chatroom.messages if message.time > float(lastUpdate)]
                return jsonify(newMessages)
            else:
                return jsonify("deleted")
        elif request.method == 'POST':
            newMessage = Message(request.form["contents"], time.time())
            chatroom = Room.query.filter_by(name = session["chatroom"]).first()
            chatroom.messages.append(newMessage)
            db.session.commit()
            lastUpdate = request.form["last"]
            newMessages = [message.makeDict() for message in chatroom.messages if message.time > float(lastUpdate)]
            return jsonify(newMessages)
    else:
        return render_template("blocked.html")
```

I am still new to AJAX, JSON, and just js in general so this might just be yet another issue with using a js alert messing with the DOM. Any help would be greatly appriciated!

Comment: Did you check to ensure that your non dev tools window has the most up to date code? devtools often disables cache so maybe you are getting an old version that doesn't have the alert code in it?

Comment: @AndrewMacNaughton I made sure that the cache was being reset every time I updated the code by right clicking on the refresh button and clicking the "Empty Cache and Hard Reload" option as I was having that issue before.

Comment: Have you tried stepping thru it with the debugger? Maybe add a console log as well and see if that gets hit. Its also possible that you have selected "Ignore popups from the page" or something similar too. I would try 1 firefox session and 1 chrome session. I don't think its a code issue.